# page variable not being replaced

Tags: hugo

I just started using Hugo with the Kiss template, but I cant seem to get variables to work.

In my page, I defined the variable imgPad here:

```
---
title: "Hugo Blog on Azure"
date: 2018-12-09T15:51:09-05:00
draft: false
imgPad: 14
---
```

Below, I try to use it like this:

```
<img alt="Deploy to Static Website" src="img/hugo-blog-on-azure/azure_storage_deploy.png" style="width: 500px; display:block; padding: {{ .imgPad }}"/>
```

In the browser the {{ .imgPad }} does not get replaced with anything. What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Page Level Params](https://gohugo.io/variables/page/#page-level-params)

It needs to be accessed as

```
{{ .Params.imgpad }}
```

Note the lower case.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I get this as a result in the browser: <img alt="Successful deployment" src="img/hugo-blog-on-azure/azure_storage_deploy2.png" style="width: 500px; display:block; padding: {{ .Params.imgPad }}">

Answer (score 1):

> Didn't work for me, I get this as a result in the browser:

```
<img alt="Successful deployment" src="img/hugo-blog-on-azure/azure_storage_deploy2.png" style="width: 500px; display:block; 
padding: {{ .Params.imgPad }}">
                    ^^^^^^
```

There still is an uppercase letter.
As described [in this thread](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/values-being-lowercased/14698/4), use in your fragment template, *and* in your front-page only lowercase variables.

Example:

> ```
> ingredients:
>   - ingredient: Club Soda
>     amount: 4oz
>   - ingredient: Gin
>     amount: 2oz
>   - ingredient: Lemon Juice
>     amount: 1oz
>   - ingredient: Simple Syrup
>     amount: 1tsp
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> {{ range .Params.ingredients }}
>  {{ .ingredient }} {{ .amount }}
> {{ end }}
> ```

Every variable is in lowercase here.